# rhino.commons unit of work

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, rhino-commons

i'm trying to get multi tenancy working in my app - using nhibernate integration facility from castle and i think that the funky combination of using the nh facility combined with fluent is making the task of configuring more than one session factory a pain.

i'm thinking about swapping it out to use the rhino.commons UoW implementation - is this the best way to go?

I'm not that experienced with nhibernate and would prefer to use a framework over a role my own as i know i will introduce more bugs that way :)

w://

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to answer my own question - rhino.commons is being discontinued - there is a small group of guys (myself included) who hope to clean, separate, re-home and maintain the project.

for now i am sticking with castle windsor and nhib integration for multi session management.